# Trying to add a product image with Spring webmvc

Tags: spring, image, spring-mvc, product

I have a problem when I try to upload a picture to a product, within the addProduct.jsp, it should save the picture with the product ID as name + the .png extension.

Everything is working just fine, it add products to database, it retrieves them, but I would want to be able to asign a picture to a product.

addProduct.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

    <%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" %>



    <!-- ADD PRODUCT JSP
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Add Product</h1>

                <p class="lead">Enter the product information: </p>
            </div>

            <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/productInventory/addProduct" method="post" 
                commandName="product" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <form:input path="productName" id="name" class="form-Control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="category">Category</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category" 
                                                                    value="electronicDevice"/>Electronic Device</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category" 
                                                                    value="smartphone"/>Smartphone</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCategory" id="category" 
                                                                    value="accessory"/>Accessory</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <form:textarea path="productDescription" id="description" class="form-Control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <form:input path="productPrice" id="price" class="form-Control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="condition">Condition</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition" 
                                                                    value="new"/>new</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productCondition" id="condition" 
                                                                    value="used"/>used</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="status">Status</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status" 
                                                                    value="active"/>active</label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline"><form:radiobutton path="productStatus" id="status" 
                                                                    value="inactive"/>inactive</label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="unitsInStock">Units in stock</label>
                    <form:input path="unitsInStock" id="unitsInStock" class="form-Control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="manufacturer">Manufacturer</label>
                    <form:input path="productManufacturer" id="manufacturer" class="form-Control"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="productImage">Upload Picture</label>
                    <form:input id="productImage" path="productImage" type="file" class="form:input-large"/>
                </div>



                <br><br>

                <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory" />" class="btn btn-default">cancel</a>
            </form:form>


<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

HomeController.java

```
 package ro.store.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import ro.store.dao.ProductDao;
import ro.store.model.Product;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private Path path;

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList")
    public String getProducts(Model model) {

        List<Product> products = productDao.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "productList"; 
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productList/viewProduct/{productId}")
    public String viewProduct(@PathVariable long productId, Model model) throws IOException{

        Product product = productDao.getProductById(productId);
        model.addAttribute(product);

        return "viewProduct";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String adminPage(){
        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/productInventory")
    public String productInventory(Model model){

        List<Product> products = productDao.getAllProducts();
        model.addAttribute("products", products);

        return "productInventory";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/productInventory/addProduct")
    public String addProduct(Model model){

        Product product = new Product();
        product.setProductCategory("electronicDevice");
        product.setProductCondition("new");
        product.setProductStatus("active");

        model.addAttribute("product", product);

        return "addProduct";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin/productInventory/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addProductPost(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, HttpServletRequest request){
        //saving the new product
        productDao.addProduct(product);

        //saving product picture in resources/images
        //define a multipart file, retrive that from product model
        MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
        //get the http session, real path of root directory (webapp) - dynamic path - different when uploaded to server, or diff computer
        String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        //here we store the image
        path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId() + ".png");

        if (productImage != null && !productImage.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException("Product image saving failed", e);
            }
        }

        return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin/productInventory/deleteProduct/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable long id, Model model) {

        productDao.deleteProduct(id);

        return "redirect:/admin/productInventory";
    }

}
```

Product.java

```
 package ro.store.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long productId;
    private String productName;
    private String productCategory;
    private String productDescription;
    private double productPrice;
    private String productCondition;
    private String productStatus;
    private int unitsInStock;
    private String productManufacturer;

    //when we persist this pojo to a database, we do not want the pic to be persistet to the database
    @Transient
    private MultipartFile productImage;

    public long getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductCategory() {
        return productCategory;
    }

    public void setProductCategory(String productCategory) {
        this.productCategory = productCategory;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public double getProductPrice() {
        return productPrice;
    }

    public void setProductPrice(double productPrice) {
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
    }

    public String getProductCondition() {
        return productCondition;
    }

    public void setProductCondition(String productCondition) {
        this.productCondition = productCondition;
    }

    public String getProductStatus() {
        return productStatus;
    }

    public void setProductStatus(String productStatus) {
        this.productStatus = productStatus;
    }

    public int getUnitsInStock() {
        return unitsInStock;
    }

    public void setUnitsInStock(int unitsInStock) {
        this.unitsInStock = unitsInStock;
    }

    public String getProductManufacturer() {
        return productManufacturer;
    }

    public void setProductManufacturer(String productManufacturer) {
        this.productManufacturer = productManufacturer;
    }

    public MultipartFile getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(MultipartFile productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }



}
```

ProductDao.java

```
 package ro.store.dao;

import java.util.List;

import ro.store.model.Product;

public interface ProductDao {

    void addProduct(Product product);

    Product getProductById(long id);

    List<Product> getAllProducts();

    void deleteProduct(long id);
}
```

ProductDaoImpl.java

```
    package ro.store.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import ro.store.dao.ProductDao;
import ro.store.model.Product;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class ProductDaoImpl implements ProductDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /*
    // not needed
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }
    */

    public void addProduct(Product product){
        //Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

        session.saveOrUpdate(product);
        session.flush();
    }

    public Product getProductById(long id){
        //Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

        Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, id);
        session.flush();

        return product;
    }

    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        //Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }


        Query query = session.createQuery("from Product");
        List<Product> products = query.list();
        session.flush();

        return products;
    }

    public void deleteProduct(long id){
        //Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Session session;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        }

        session.delete(getProductById(id));
        session.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one comment regarding transactionality: since you're using @Transactional in your DAO at class level, you don't need to explicitly open Hibernate Sessions: `session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();`, Spring will handle it for you

Comment: BTW, what's your problem? It's not clear...

Comment: thank you! Will keep it in mind.

Comment: This is a web app using spring. When I add a product tu the productInventory, it works, but I want to also add a product image to the product. It does not make any errors, just does not copy the product image in the images folder, where I give it the path in the HomeController:         path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId() + ".png");

Comment: Does it reach this line? -> `productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString()));`

Comment: Yes, this is console output in debug perspective:   2016-05-26 12:39:32 DEBUG CommonsMultipartFile:149 - Multipart file 'productImage' with original filename [new-macbook-main.jpg], stored at [/Applications/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.3.SR1/base-instance/work/Catalina/localhost/Magazin-online/upload__11882ac1_154ec6dbc20__7ffb_00000008.tmp]: moved to [/Applications/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.3.SR1/base-instance/wtpwebapps/Magazin-online/\WEB-INF\resources\images\21.png]

Comment: But when I go to "WEB-INF/resources/images" the 21.png is not there.

Comment: That's weird, it looks good... Try debugging into this statement `this.fileItem.write(dest);` from `CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo()`

Comment: I think it is a path problem. I changed this line        path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "\\WEB-INF\\resources\\images\\" + product.getProductId() + ".png"); to         path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "/WEB-INF/resources/images/" + product.getProductId() + ".png"); ---->> and in the "pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.1.3.SR1/base-instance/wt‌​pwebapps/Magazin-online/" I got the file: "\WEB-INF\resources\images\28.png". So it means it works, I'm just missing something with the path :-?, it takes the picture, but somethings up when it tryes to save it to the  "WEB-INF/resources/images"  directory